# RestKit 0.20.0 - getObjectsAtPath with JSON HTTP Body request

Tags: objective-c, ios, restkit, afnetworking

In [RestKit](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/) Version 0.10.x I used

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/special/path" usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader *loader) {
            loader.objectMapping = aMapping;
            loader.delegate = _delegate;
            loader.method = RKRequestMethodPOST;
            loader.userData = [MobileGatewayReauthentication class];
            loader.params = [anDictionary toJsonRKParam];
        }];
```

to add a `NSDictionary` to `loader.params` to send a collection of parameters as the HTTP body of the request.

---

Since RestKit 0.20.0 the method `loadObjectsAtResourcePath` has been replaced by the following method, where it is no longer possible to pass a `NSDictionary` in `parameters`, which is used as HTTP Body (JSON encoded):

```
[RKObjectManager.sharedManager getObjectsAtPath:path parameters:params success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult)
{
    NSLog(@"success");
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"failure");
}];
```

When working with `[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].HTTPClient` ([AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)) it works like a charm when setting:

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].HTTPClient setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].HTTPClient postPath:path parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", operation.responseString);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@",error.localizedDescription);
}];
```

But I need the higher-level object mapper.

---

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].HTTPClient setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];
```

has no effect on [RKObjectManager sharedManager] but

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].HTTPClient setDefaultHeader:@"aHeader" value:@"aValue"];
```

has. So I assumed that `setParameterEncoding` works, too.

Is it a bug, is it not yet implemented, or have I missed something?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really have missed something.

`loadObjectsAtResourcePath` get's (for sure) called with `RKRequestMethodGET`. So the parameters get append to the URL, not to the HTTP body.

To append the parametrs as a JSON HTTP body, you have to use a post method, for example

```
- (void)postObject:(id)object
              path:(NSString *)path
        parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
           success:(void (^)(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult))success
           failure:(void (^)(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure;
```

Excuse the hasty question. I should have seen it before.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, RestKit creator pushed something in the development branch (which is always tested and pretty safe to use) that might fix your problem ([Commit here](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/commit/b9457ce65c475fb748d31d009bfc38518112e990)), which basically sets by default this:

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].HTTPClient setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:RKMIMETypeJSON];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].HTTPClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
```

Hope this help!

Comment: I pulled the latest development branch commit, but it did't work. I've edited the question to clarify my needs.

Answer (score 0):

There could be problem with the **path** in getObjectsAtPath:path
If you are using slash (/) in the beginning of path, move it end of baseurl as shown in example below.

```
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://rest.example.com:8080/test/"];
    AFHTTPClient* client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];


[objectManager getObjectsAtPath:@"rest/updates"
                         parameters:nil
                            success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
                                NSLog(@"success");
                            }
                            failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                NSLog(@"failure");
                            }];
```